# SQL Server 2008 Modified WHERE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

My SQL Server 2008 table is constructed as follows:
160 columns consisting of a Ratio_ID and 160 companies as headers
742 rows consisting of the Ratio_ID's per company.

The typical structure would be:

> Ratio_ID       | Company 1 | Company 2 | To Company 160
>
> > part03x0       |  0.01     | 0.03      |
> >     To Ratio_ID742 |

How would I be able to run a Query to request All Companies Where Ratio_ID part03x0 is zero?

Tried to Google this, but explaining it is very difficult.

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: _"160 columns"_ why??? Normalize your table, these companies belong into their own table and you just have to link both tables via relation table.

Comment: It will better if you [***normalize***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table, and create two tables one for `Companies` and another for `Parts` and create foreign keys for thiem in the first table, it will be easier.

Comment: like the other two comments have said, normalize your data, company names as headers is insane

Comment: Rethought what I was busy doing, and will take your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you storing the companies as columns?  The companies should be placed in their own table, with a unique ID referring to each company.  You can than use this ID with the Ratio_ID in order to perform the query.

160 columns is a massive overkill. [Here](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/#.UicpKTYwrhQ) is a nice tutorial on how to normalize your database.

*EDIT:*

You do not need to have  a table for each company.  You only need one table named, for example, **tbl_Company** and just add the following:

```
company_id  |  company_name


    1       |   CompanyNameOne
    2       |   CompanyNameTwo
    3       |   CompanyNameThree
```

Another table for your Ratios, **tbl_Ratio**

```
 ratio_id   |   ratio_name

    1       |    RatioNameOne
    2       |    RatioNameTwo
```

Then combine both using `ForeignKeys` and `Relationships` between the two tables into a separate table as below:

**tbl_Company_Ratio**

```
company_id   |   ratio_id    | ratio_amount

   1               2              5
   1               1              2
   3               2              10
   2               2              5
  ....
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be creating a new variable called Company_Ratio_ID and then just have the calendar months on top. I need to have annual data in a table, having a table per company is too much work in terms of populating the data.